# How to resize a Base64 encoded Data URI PNG using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, image-resizing, data-uri

I have a Base64 encoded PNG squeezed out of a web socket into a web page, that I display using Data URI

```
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, --base64 png-- ">
```

Is there a way in javascript or some of its flavours to resize the image I receive into a smaller base64 data URI equivalent, as to dinamically generate a thumbnail version of the given image?

Or maybe I could just duplicate the HTML Image object and play with it as a whole, using some obscure jQuery magic trick that I haven't find out yet.

If this can be done in javascript on client side, I could avoid another HTTP request to my server deamon, which would take some time to reprocess and deliver the resized image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone image with jQuery, and as for resizing - maybe trivial changing width and height of html element?

```
$('.somewhere img').clone().appendTo('.elsewhere').width(16).height(16)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pixastic library will do that and it work surprisingly fast, even on a mobile device.

Try someting like :

```
    Pixastic.process(image, "resize", { "width" : 200, "height" : 200 }, function (oCanvas){ //callback code here});
```

I struggled though with the fact that you give it an image and it return a Canvas, took me weeks to understand what was going on !!!
Now I use Canvas2Image I found somewhere on the web to get back to an image.

Answer (score 0):

The [maxImage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) plugin claims to be able to resize images.   TMMV, I have not tried this myself.